# my static folder where I place my js ans css files is not at the root of my django project. How to call these satic files in the template?

Tags: django

Here is the configuration of my static_root variable:
`STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'vol/web/static')]`
My templates are at the root of the project.

```
TEMPLATES={
    ...
    'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    ...
}
```

This is how I call my bootstrap.min.css file in a project template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

But it doesn't work because the file is not loaded. What's the right way to do it?

---

Comment: both template and CSS not loading?

Comment: The HTML is rendered, but CSS file does not load? Is it your local environment (django dev server with DEBUG), or staging/production deployment?

Comment: only css and js are not loaded.

Comment: I assume that it happens during local development. See my answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside main urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings as SETTINGS
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(SETTINGS.STATIC_URL, document_root=SETTINGS.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(SETTINGS.MEDIA_URL, document_root=SETTINGS.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR / 'static',)
STATIC_ROOT = (BASE_DIR / 'static'/ 'static')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you store your js and css files in some folder, then you need to specify this folder in `STATICFILES_DIRS` django setting. For example:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  "/home/my-user/my-project/static",
]
```

Then Django will search this directory(ies) when looking up files specified in `{% static ... %}` tag.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs

2. If Django still unable to find particular file, try using `findstatic` management command for diagnostics. This will show in which directories django is actually looking for the file. For example:

```
python manage.py findstatic -v3 assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic